# Step my script not its imports - functionality?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, pydev

It is actually a credit to the strength of PyDev/ Eclipse that the debugger also steps through the corresponding parts of the imported numpy/pandas, at the places their functionalities are used by my script e.g. df = pandas.dataframe({...

But if I am confident that the imports work OK: Is there a way for the debugger to step only through my own 10 lines of script and not its imports? It would save a lot of inspection time.

(Eclipse for C/C++ on Windows 10 64bit)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually such functionality available in the debugger, but it currently doesn't have an UI (still didn't have time to implement it).

Still, you can set an environment variable to use it.

I.e.: add an environment variable named **PYDEVD_FILTERS** (you can add it in the interpreter configuration or by editing your launch) and set it to be a list of paths which match the directories you want to ignore separated by `;` (fnmatch style) -- those matches will be skipped by the debugger.

See: https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/master/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_utils.py#L191 as a reference for this (i.e.: `pydevd_utils.is_ignored_by_filter`).

Comment: Thanks so much, that's great Fabio! I appreciate the time you took to reply. I will have a look. All the best